# Azure REST API to list all registered applications (Azure Active Directory)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rest-api

I am looking for fetch the list of registered applications (include client Id & client secert) based on tenant Id or subscription. I have checked the this link - Azure Active Directory Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api
but getting confused like why do we need to use Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Graph API to get the list of all registered applications because the applications are part of Azure AD.

As such, these applications have nothing to do with Azure Subscriptions unless you give the applications specific access to connect to and manage your Azure Subscriptions through API permissions.

There are separate set of APIs to deal with App Registrations (Applications in Azure Portal) and Service Principals (Enterprise Applications in Azure Portal).

App Registrations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0

Service Principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0

Please note that you will not be able to get client secret through any of the APIs. Client secret is only displayed/returned at the time of creation. After that it is never shown/returned.

You may also find this link useful in understanding the relationship between App Registrations and Service Principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals.